# What is the behavior of an image URL which contains 2 occurrences of protocol://?

Tags: image, url

I find on the odysee.com video site that the URLs for thumbnail images contain 2 occurrences of `https://`, eg:

`https://image-processor.vanwanet.com/optimize/s:390:220/quality:85/plain/https://thumbnails.lbry.com/cW11rfzDIDA`

Is the second `https:` treated as the name of a directory, and the following `//` simply collapse into a single `/` (as they normally would?)

Or does the server interpret this as something different?

I am examining these URLs because I find that in Firefox, the images do not cache, while in Chrome they do.  This happens even when I create my own minimal test page with several images using the same odysee.com thumbnail image URLs, bringing me to the conclusion that the issue is not related to the odysee.com page in any way.

(Another thing I observe is that these images load extremely slow, sometimes failing to load, sometimes not. But that may just be a shortcoming of the hosting website. This is true on either browser.)

Comment: Side note: url/uri can only have one "scheme" part... The one you call "the second protocol" is simply a part of the path where `:` is allowed to be present (the other colons did not surprise you in the same url for some reason) and empty path segments ("//") are handled on protocol specific basis - for HTTP usually just collapse.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks. `:` wouldn't have surprised me here either, except for the fact that it coincidentally is a part of `https://` in the middle of the string. Its presence seems not merely coincidental, and if it is part of a path, it is an interesting choice in file naming.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first protocol is used as a protocol and the other is just part of the URL. The image-processor.vanwanet.com server will receive a request that looks something like this:

```
GET /optimize/s:390:220/quality:85/plain/https://thumbnails.lbry.com/cW11rfzDIDA HTTP/1.1
```

And it can choose to do whatever it wants with that information. In this case it's probably using everything after the "plain/" as a URL and using that for something. A reason to do it like that instead of putting the thumbnails.lbry.com URL in a query parameter is that a query parameter needs percent encoding but a URL in a URL doesn't. This makes the full thing shorter and maybe easier to process.